# Is there a way to to convert ISBNdb curl to php?

Tags: php, curl

I've never worked with `curl` before and I want to rephrase this to something that works in php. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://api2.isbndb.com/books' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: 47296_a0846561675961d9272454ea90b82240' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d 'isbns=9780738726243,9780738747842,9780738756707,9780738765457'
```

Comment: You can try the following website: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ It will show you the PHP Curl Equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

With your initial curl query:

```
curl -X 'POST'
'https://api2.isbndb.com/books'

-H 'accept: application/json'
-H 'Authorization: 47296_a0846561675961d9272454ea90b82240'
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'

-d 'isbns=9780738726243,9780738747842,9780738756707,9780738765457'
```

The `-H` switch signifies a `header` value and `-d` indicates the POST request body itself. With that in mind using the following simple function and configuration should yield the desired result.

```
function curl( $url=NULL, $options=NULL, $headers=false ){
    /*
        Download a copy of CACERT.pem from
        https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
        
        save to webserver and modify the $cacert variable
        to suit - ensuring that the path you choose is
        readable.
    */
    $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';    #modify this path
    $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

    /* Initialise curl request object */
    $curl=curl_init();
    if( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
    }

    /* Define standard options */
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, trim( $url ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
    
    /* enhanced debug */
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );
    

    /* Assign runtime parameters as options to override defaults. */
    if( isset( $options ) && is_array( $options ) ){
        foreach( $options as $param => $value ) curl_setopt( $curl, $param, $value );
    }
    
    /* send additional headers with the request */
    if( $headers && is_array( $headers ) ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    }

    /* Execute the request and store responses */
    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'status'    =>  curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE ),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
    );
    rewind( $vbh );
    $res->verbose=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
    fclose( $vbh );
    curl_close( $curl );
    
    return $res;
}
```

And then set the configuration

```
$url='https://api2.isbndb.com/books';

# The POST BODY
$payload=array( 
    'isbns' => '9780738726243, 9780738747842, 9780738756707, 9780738765457'
);

# an array of headers to send with the request. The above function processes this array as it is.
$headers=array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: 47296_a0846561675961d9272454ea90b82240',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

# instruct curl to make a POST request and include the POST body
$options=array(
    CURLOPT_POST        =>  true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  =>  $payload
);

# make the request & proceed if the response status is 200 OK
$res=curl( $url, $options, $headers );

if( $res->status==200 ){
    $json=json_decode( $res->response );

    # do interesting things with the data...
    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($json));
}
```

Which ultimately yields this response:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [total] => 2
    [requested] => 4
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [publisher] => Llewellyn Publications
                    [language] => en_US
                    [image] => https://images.isbndb.com/covers/78/42/9780738747842.jpg
                    [title_long] => 365 Days of Hoodoo: Daily Rootwork, Mojo & Conjuration
                    [dimensions] => Height: 7.9 inches, Length: 5.3 inches, Width: 1 inches
                    [pages] => 432
                    [date_published] => 2018-12-08T00:00:01Z
                    [authors] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Bird, Stephanie Rose
                        )

                    [title] => 365 Days of Hoodoo: Daily Rootwork, Mojo & Conjuration
                    [isbn13] => 9780738747842
                    [msrp] => 19.99
                    [binding] => Paperback
                    [isbn] => 073874784X
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [publisher] => Llewellyn Publications
                    [title_long] => How To Use A Crystal: 50 Practical Rituals And Spiritual Activities For Inspiration And Well-being
                    [pages] => 312
                    [date_published] => 2018-11-08
                    [authors] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Richard Webster
                        )

                    [title] => How To Use A Crystal: 50 Practical Rituals And Spiritual Activities For Inspiration And Well-being
                    [isbn13] => 9780738756707
                    [msrp] => 16.99
                    [binding] => Paperback
                    [isbn] => 0738756709
                )

        )

)
```